# Catch the root command exit code from a regular user

Tags: shell, root, exit-status, non-root-user

I've been researching `umount` exit codes for some error cases, running the following command repeatedly:

```bsh
$ sudo sh -c "umount /home; echo $?"
```

And got surprisingly strange results. The error message was always `umount: /home: target is busy.`, but the error code was sometimes 0, sometimes 32. And even sometimes 16 in case `/bin/bash` used instead of `sh`.

But if I get the exit code as root:

```bsh
# umount /home; echo $?
```

I always have the exit code of 32.

Please, explain how can the first command give that different results.
And I really wonder, is there an one-liner to fetch the exit code of a root command from a regular user?

Comment: You're using double quotes. `$?` is expanded by your shell before the `sudo` command is executed.

Comment: @muru Yes, thanks a lot! I completely forgot about variable substitution in double-quoted strings %)